# On Travis, what is the easiest way to identify a build on a branch triggered by a push and a PR merged into it?

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, travis-ci

At the moment, I have a situation where I'd like my travis build to trigger a deploy when commits are pushed directly to the development branch or when a PR is merged into it. I haven't been able to use Travis' environment variables to achieve this so far.

I have tried 2 things so far

1. Using the [deploy](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/script/) job. The problem with this is that it is not triggered when a PR is merged into development because the resulting build is a [`Pull Request Build`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#pull-requests) which deploy does not apply to.
2. Using the `after_success` job with a conditional that checks if it's a PR and if the base branch of the PR is development

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" ] && [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "AC-6810" ]; then
    # do deploy
fi;
```

This is not a plan because even an open PR to development causes this condition to be true. It should only be true when the PR is merged.

Any help is welcome here, the environment variables given don't seem to give me the power to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the condition I was using to determine when to do a deploy was not correct, it should have been

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" = "false" ] && [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "AC-6810" ]; then
    # do deploy
fi;
```

and this way we would `# do deploy` when a commit is pushed to AC-6810 or when a PR is merged into AC-6810